# Symfony3 - Dynamic Drop down from a yaml file

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I want to populate a drop down list from a yaml file values

I created a separate yaml file

> config/test.yml

```
test:
  - test1
  - test2
  - test3
```

Calling this one in

> config.yml

```
imports:
 - { resource: test.yml }

parameters:    
 testing:
      "%test%"
```

Now using this one in form

```
->add('test', ChoiceType::class, array('label' => 'Testing',
                'choices' => $this->getParameter('testing')))
```

It is working but drop down is showing indexes i.e 0, 1, 2 instead of values.

**Other things I tried,** 
**Trial 1**

> test.yml

```
option1: test1
option2: test2
option3: test3
```

> config.yml

```
testing:
 "%option1%": "%option1%"
 "%option2%": "%option2%"
 "%option3%": "%option3%"
```

This thing works but I dont change two files everytime I add a new option

**Trial 2**
 Just changed the

> config.yml

```
testing:
 "%test%"
```

Dropdown menu is showing option1, option2 and option3.

I would want to see test1, test2, test3.

I even thought of something like

> test.yml

```
test:
 test1:test1
 test2:test2
 test3:test3
```

but in real case my test1 test2 test3 values are too big, so don't want to make my test.yml look ugly with same text twice

Is there any better method to do this or did I cover all the scenarios?

Comment: Answer to the question is in the comments of the answer I have selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array_flip()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php):

```
test:
  - test1
  - test2
  - test3

testing:
    "%test%"


'choices' => array_flip($this->getParameter('testing'))
```

Result:

```
<option value="0">test1</option>
<option value="1">test2</option>
<option value="2">test3</option>
```

Comment: I want to store the value that is being shown, i.e. in this case I want to store test1, test2, test3 instead of 0, 1, 2. I will be retrieving it from the database to display in some other part of the application

Comment: So use `array_combine()`,  `'choices' => array_combine($this->getParameter('testing'), $this->getParameter('testing'))`

Comment: Is there any document or link that describes all the "array_anyoption" in symfony, It will be very useful. Thanks